# Mirzakhani's hyperbolic method generalized to moduli space of stable maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, teichmuller-theory

I've been learning about Mirzakhani's use of hyperbolic geometry to compute Weil-Petersson volumes of moduli space of curves, and the application to proving Virasoro constraints for a point. Why have these methods not been directly extended to higher dimensional target spaces? I don't know much about the structure of the moduli space of stable maps into a projective variety. Is there expected to exist a reasonable definition of volume for these spaces? I'm further confused by the fact that "topological recursion" introduced by Eyndard-Orantin, and inspired by Mirzakhani's recursion relations, was used to compute Gromov-Witten invariants for toric Calabi-Yau 3-folds. I suppose my question is: to what extent might one expect that intersection theory on the moduli space of stable maps into a projective variety is related to the hyperbolic geometry of the domain Riemann surface?

Comment: I'm not expert enough to know if this is a "good" question, but it's definitely a very interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mirzakhani's computation of volumes of deformation spaces is very heavily based on the work of Greg McShane (McShane's identity). McShane's theory has been extended to other deformation spaces, see, for example

*Labourie, François; McShane, Gregory*, [**Cross ratios and identities for higher Teichmüller-Thurston theory**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/00127094-2009-040), Duke Math. J. 149, No. 2, 279-345 (2009). [ZBL1182.30075](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1182.30075).

(a search of Google Scholar for "McShane Labourie" reveals a fair bit of other work). So, for the last question, the answer is "not very", but feel free to read the papers...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I’m confused. How do the spaces in that paper relate to moduli spaces of stable maps into a projective variety (such that appear in Gromov-Witten theory?)

Comment: @JohnRached I did not say they did relate. Your question was whether the methods are intrinsically hyperbolic-geometric, and these references show that they are not.